# Ionic + React - Evitar envió del formulario al pulsar botón de tipo submit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic

Tengo un **formulario en Ionic + React**, intento que NO SE ENVÍE al pulsar un botón *submit* de *Ionic*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He asociado la función `handleFormSubmit()` a un `onClick` en el botón con las instrucciones `event.preventDefault()` y `event.stopPropagation()` en su interior, pero no funcionan.

Este es el formulario:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    IonApp,
    IonButton,
    IonCol,
    IonContent,
    IonGrid,
    IonInput,
    IonItem,
    IonLabel,
    IonPage,
    IonRow,
    IonTextarea
} from '@ionic/react';


function Trans(props: any)
{
    const { ...other } = props;

    return <span {...other} />
}
class FormTest extends Component
{
  appPageHome = "/";

  render()
  {
    return (
        <IonApp>
            <IonPage>
                <IonContent>
                    <form name="test-form">
                        <IonGrid>
                            <IonRow>
                                <IonCol size="1"></IonCol>
                                <IonCol size="10">
                                    <IonItem>
                                        <IonLabel position="stacked" color="primary">
                                            <Trans>Nombre</Trans>:
                                        </IonLabel>
                                        <IonInput
                                            name="username"
                                            type="text"
                                            spellCheck={false}
                                            autocapitalize="off"
                                            required />
                                    </IonItem>
                                </IonCol>
                            </IonRow>
                            <IonRow>
                                <IonCol size="1"></IonCol>
                                <IonCol size="10">
                                    <IonItem>
                                        <IonLabel position="stacked" color="primary">
                                            <Trans>Mensaje</Trans>:
                                        </IonLabel>
                                        <IonTextarea
                                            name="message"
                                            autocapitalize="on"
                                            required>
                                        </IonTextarea>
                                    </IonItem>
                                </IonCol>
                            </IonRow>
                        </IonGrid>

                        <IonRow>
                            <IonCol size="1"></IonCol>
                            <IonCol size="5">
                                <IonButton
                                    routerLink={this.appPageHome}
                                    color="light"
                                    expand="block">
                                    <Trans>Cancelar</Trans>
                                </IonButton>
                            </IonCol>
                            <IonCol size="5">
                                <IonButton
                                    type="submit"
                                    expand="block"
                                    onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                                    <Trans>Enviar</Trans>
                                </IonButton>
                            </IonCol>
                        </IonRow>
                    </form>
                </IonContent>
            </IonPage>
        </IonApp>
    );
  }


  sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
  handleFormSubmit = async (event: any) =>
  {
      const e = event || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      await this.sleep(1000);
      window.alert('Mensaje enviado...');
  }
}

export default FormTest;
```

Código completo: https://github.com/oricis/ionic_react_ts__one/tree/form-tests

Answer (score 0):

El error esta en el posicionamiento del evento.

Cuando designas un evento `onClick` en un botón y posteriormente en dicho evento tienes `e.preventDefault()`. Estas evitando el funcionamiento del botón y no así del formulario.

EL evento `submit` es propio de `form`, es por ese motivo que tu código no realiza lo que deseas.

La solución es cambiar el evento a tu etiqueta `form`:

```
<form name="test-form" onSubmit={subirInfo}>
```

Y suponiendo que tu `IonButton` sea un `button`, tu botón quedaría así:

```
<IonButton
   type="submit"
   expand="block"
   <Trans>Enviar</Trans>
</IonButton>
```

Luego en tu función debería bastar con `preventDefault` aparte de eso solo le cambie el nombre:

```
subirInfo = async (event: any) =>
{
  const e = event || window.event;
  e.preventDefault();

  await this.sleep(1000);
  window.alert('Mensaje enviado...');
}
```

Comment: Ok, con un `onSubmit()` en el `form` funciona, si usas `e.stopPropagation()` ya había probado tu solución con `e.preventDefault()`, que es lo habitual en los formularios... **Cosas de *Ionic***.